# Published android app is not visible any where in google play

Tags: android

I have published an android widget in google play. It was one week from the day i published my application and i am not able to find this app any where in google play.

I could see the status as published in google play but i even not able to access using the direct link as some said in other similar questions.

I have around 10 applications in google play and this is my 11th application.

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Induz+App+Developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Induz%20App%20Developers)

I have published the application in the similar way what i did for other apps. Only difference is that all other applications has the launcher activity but as this is the widget i don't have any activity in the manifest file.

Can anybody give some pointers here?

Answer (score 0):

Its native application or a hybrid app because we have seen  such problems with hybrid application.

Comment: it is a simple android app widget which displays operator name and signal.. Nothing more than that..

Comment: i mean h have written it in java or using web technology

Comment: No i have written in java and not using any web technology.. Is there any solution to make this work..